# Sql Server - Get first record from a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2uLQBT0.jpg]

I tried below code to get first record from "AdID" group

```
;with cte as
(
  select
    ADID,
    PhotoName,
    PhotoPath,
    rank() over(partition by AdID order by PhotoName) as rn
  from AdPhoto
)  
select ADID,
    PhotoName,
    PhotoPath
from cte
where rn = 1
```

But it turns out the output like this

```
AD1001  temptemp_1.jpeg ~/UserUploads/temptemp/
AD1002  temptemp_10.jpg ~/UserUploads/temptemp/
```

I want a output like this

```
AD1001  temptemp_1.jpeg ~/UserUploads/temptemp/
AD1002  temptemp_5.jpg  ~/UserUploads/temptemp/
```

Please help

Comment: If your shown data is accurate, it seems you want to to order your rank by id. If you want to order by your "Number" portion of the file name you'll need to run a substring to get just the number from the filename and order by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `order by ID` instead of `order by PhotoName`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select
    ADID,
    PhotoName,
    PhotoPath,
    rank() over(partition by AdID order by ID) as rn
  from AdPhoto
)  
select ADID,
    PhotoName,
    PhotoPath
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Another question what if "ID" Column is not available. How do u fetch a record

Answer (score 0):

This will help for this particular set of data:

```
;with cte as
(
  select
    ADID,
    PhotoName,
    PhotoPath,
    rank() over(partition by AdID order by len(PhotoName) asc, PhotoName) as rn
  from AdPhoto
)  
select ADID,
    PhotoName,
    PhotoPath
from cte
where rn = 1
```

But I'd suggest to either change naming scheme for the photoname, or find some other ordering algoritm.

Comment: Thanks yours too helped. I really like the idea of Changing Naming scheme for PhotoName. Can you suggest a few